# display alert when data is changed using flutter?

Tags: flutter

[My screen look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQtFU.jpg)I have trying to display alert when snapshot.data value has been changed.i try the if else condition

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:assets_audio_player/assets_audio_player.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
```

import'package:flutter_custom_clippers/flutter_custom_clippers.dart';

```
import 'package:tv_dashboard/pages/test.dart';
//import 'package:assets_audio_player/assets_audio_player.dart';

class DashBoard extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DashBoardState createState() => _DashBoardState();
}

var now = new DateTime.now();
String g = ('${now.day}-${now.month}-${now.year}');
AnimationController _controller;
Animation<double> _animation;

class _DashBoardState extends State<DashBoard> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  Timer timer;
  int counter = 0;
  Test data = Test();
  Future<List<dynamic>> fetchUsers() async {
    String url = 'http://us.rdigs.com/jsonData.php';

    var result = await http.get(url, headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
    });
    if (result.statusCode == 200) {
      //print(result.body);
      //playSound();

      return json.decode(result.body);
    } else {
      // If the server not return a 200 OK ,
      // then throw the exception.
      throw Exception('Failed');
    }
  }

  playSound() async {
    AssetsAudioPlayer audioPlayer = AssetsAudioPlayer();
    audioPlayer.open(Audio('assets/Ring.mp3'));
  }

  String name(dynamic name) {
    return name['name'];
  }

  String leads(dynamic leads) {
    return leads['leads'];
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 5), (Timer t) => addValue());
  }

  void addValue() {
    setState(() {
      //playSound();
      counter++;
    });
  }

  void alertBox() async {
    await fetchUsers();
    Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 300),
      child: AlertDialog(
        title: Text('Alert Data'),
      ),
    ); //Use the response in the dialog
  }

  var totalLeads = 0;
  var countLead = 0;
  var allLeads;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    alertBox();
    //playSound();
    return Scaffold(
        // backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(198, 159, 169, 1),
        body: Column(
      children: [
        ClipPath(
          clipper: OvalBottomBorderClipper(),
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
            height: 70,
            color: Colors.cyan[100],
            child: Center(
                child: Column(
              children: [
                Text(
                  "Total Leads",
                  style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 28.0, fontFamily: 'Michroma'),
                ),
                Text(
                  totalLeads.toString(),
                  style: new TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 25.0,
                  ),
                )
              ],
            )),
          ),
        ),
       
        Expanded(
            child: FutureBuilder<List<dynamic>>(
                future: fetchUsers(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {

                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    //total leads
                    //alertBox();
                    totalLeads = snapshot.data
                        .map<int>((m) => int.parse(m["leads"]))
                        .reduce((a, b) => a + b);
                   

                    return GridView.builder(
                        itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                          crossAxisCount: 6,
                          childAspectRatio:
                              MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 350,
                        ),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return Card(
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                    topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(20)),
                                side: BorderSide(color: Colors.black)),
                            child: Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                                    child: Column(
                                      children: [
                                        Text(
                                          name(snapshot.data[index]),
                                          style: new TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 25.0,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Container(
                                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 12),
                                            child: Text(
                                              leads(snapshot.data[index])
                                                  .toString(),
                                              style: new TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 26.0,
                                                  color: Colors.blue),
                                            ))
                                      ],
                                    )),
                              ],
                            ),
                          );
                        });
                  } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Text("${snapshot.error}");
                  } else {
                    return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                  }
                }))
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```

totalLeads is count of my all int value
sum is temp variable

my problem is when data is changed in json string then display the alert box in flutter

Comment: There are couple of issues with your code but about your concern, the function `alertBox` just creates Container but there's no logic to present first of all.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When data changed in string, you can show [`AlertDialog`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AlertDialog-class.html) widget:

```dart
Future<void> showErrorDialog() async {
  return showDialog<void>(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return AlertDialog(
        title: Text('Error'),
        content: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Text(
            'Error message',
          ),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          TextButton(
            child: Text('Ok'),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
          ),
        ],
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: The main problem is I have fetch data from api using Future/FutureBuilder but I display the alert  when api Data is changed and I have also display the data on screen but I display the alert when data is changes

Comment: @farten , Sir I display the dialog as well as sound play after data is added

Comment: How do you updating a data in the screen?

Comment: @farten, Sir I have use FutureBuilder in code please check it and also update the my screen on question

Comment: Are you updating your screen on button or a data loading once without user interaction?

Comment: @farten,Sir screen is automatically update ,not on button click, when data is updated then display alert /play sound on screen